# Markdown for word keeps "forgetting" styles after one paragraph

Tags: r-markdown

I use R markdown in R Studio to create a word document. The styles for the document are defined in a reference document.
The following issue appears:
After any heading or equation (in the following example it is only shown with headings) the first paragraph uses the right style (the standard from the reference) but beginning with the second paragraph the font changes to Times New Roman (which is not defined at all for any style.)

**EDIT:** [Link to ref.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fin028IHd7cTpp0GOEH6e8Bs1TT87EXe)

How is it possible to fix this?

My markdown file:

```
---
title: "Samplefile"
output: 
  word_document:
      reference_docx: ref.docx
---

# Here is my first heading

This paragraph has the style it should have.

This paragraph (the second one) hast the wrong style.

A third paragraph.
```

The output is the following:
[image: Output file]

Comment: Can you share the `ref.docx` file?

Comment: Here it is: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fin028IHd7cTpp0GOEH6e8Bs1TT87EXe

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an issue of having a 'first paragraph' style and a 'text body' style (these names may not be correct). If you've only created/edited the first, then the style for the second will not be correct.

While you could try to fix this by working out what the style should be called and creating/editing it, this is likely to be a frustrating exercise if you don't know what it should be called or if you find some other style that you haven't properly edited.

An easier method is to create a template from within R-Markdown. With this method you would create a template.Rmd file (or whatever) and fill it with all the fields you are likely to need (e.g., heading 1, first paragraph, text body, etc.). Once you're done you can knit the file, change it's name (e.g., template1.docx), edit the styles in Word that are connected to the entries you made in the r-markdown file, save the file, and use the new file as the reference doc. This ensures that you're capturing all the necessary styles, which is difficult to do if you create the template in Word. If you find that you've not included something that has its own style then you can always update the template using the earlier template as the reference.

These steps are described better than what I can do here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html